# Speed up eclipse juno on windows

Tags: java, android, eclipse, performance, multicore

I have 4 GB of ram and a core 2 duo processor . I am running eclipse for android on it and its running slow. There are no other programs running on it and its only using 40% of the CPU. 
   I thought that if i could dedicate a CPU only to this program it might run faster. Any idea on how it can be achieved. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

This problem also made me think on how a multi core processor runs and why is it better then other single core systems any verified literature on this available on web.

Comment: Does your eclipse lags after using AVD ?

Comment: This isn't a proper question. If you find your eclipse is slow, you can try to allocate more memory by editing the eclipse.ini file. That's about it. If I were you, I would use something else as eclipse is painfully slow. Try Android Studio

Comment: @PrateekJoshi Nah it just takes lots of time when i load it for the first time and then the compilation and building of code is slow too...and the cpu still isnt being fully used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some `general` methods to `speed up` your **eclipse**,

1.Make sure you have **latest JDK** installed and `eclipse has reference to it`.

2.You are currently using `Juno(4.2)` , try to **install latest version** like Mars or Luna(4.4) . It is `preferable` to use **Android Studio** because it is `official IDE for Android development`.

3.As you have `4GB of RAM` ,try to modify **eclipse.ini** file

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx350m
```

Replace `-Xmx350m  with -Xmx4G` so that it **gets 4 GB of RAM** instead of **350MB** .

Answer (score 0):

There is noting magical to seed up your PC or eclipse. It seems that your CPU is not faster enough as your desire. And obviously eclipse is not very lightweight too. So there is no solution actually. And don't be frustrate by thinking that your PC or eclipse is doing something unusual. Its normal.

Comment: I wasnt asking for any magic mate :) .. all i asked for is there something that could speed this up .... cuz android studio works just fine ....

Comment: @user3027029 If you find comfortable with Android Studio, then use **that** one.